# Check if value equals 0 regardless of decimal values?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm balancing the sigma of a Gaussian kernel. I desire to break the while loop once the first index of the array is equal to `0.(any decimal value)`.

I found that simply trying to match `0` won't match if the value also contains any decimals like `0.000013301`.

```
var gaussianKernel1d = (function() {
    var sqr2pi = Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI);

    return function gaussianKernel1d(size, sigma) {
        'use strict';

        // ensure size is even and prepare variables
        var width = (size / 2) | 0,
            kernel = new Array(width * 2 + 1),
            norm = 1.0 / (sqr2pi * sigma),
            coefficient = 2 * sigma * sigma,
            total = 0,
            x;

        // set values and increment total
        for (x = -width; x <= width; x++) {
            total += kernel[width + x] = norm * Math.exp((-x * x) / coefficient);
        }

        // divide by total to make sure the sum of all the values is equal to 1
        for (x = 0; x < kernel.length; x++) {
            kernel[x] /= total;
        }

        return kernel;
    };
})();

let i = 0.01;
let kernelArray = gaussianKernel1d(512, i);
while (kernelArray[0] === 0) {
    i = i + 0.01;
    kernelArray = gaussianKernel1d(512, i);
```

Same is also true when using `Array[0] !== 0.0)`

How can I match any values in the dataset that equal 0 regardless of the decimal values? And without converting the array to integers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215176/discussion-on-question-by-srb633-check-if-value-equals-0-regardless-of-decimal-v).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

epascarello's solution is correct:

```
while (Math.floor(kernelArray[0]) === 0)
```

That will continue looping as long as `kernelArray[0]` is a value `>= 0` and `< 1`.

Or of course, the other obvious approach is just to write the equation in the description above:

```
while (kernelArray[0]) >= 0 && kernelArray[0] < 1)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try following

$b = 0;

`while ( (string) Array[0] !== (string) $b) { 
  // code that just regenerates the random values
}`

Comment: This isn't even JavaScript.

Comment: What is (string) referring to?

Comment: This one is solution you don;t need to check syntax

Comment: @srb633 (string) reefers to type casting of that value

Comment: Except of course, JavaScript is loosely typed, it doesn't *have* casting, which is a concept specific to strongly-typed languages. (it does have *conversion*, but you don't do it that way...hence my comment that this isn't JavaScript.)

Comment: I don't know of any language where this would work anyway. Casting `0.000013301` to a string won't make it equal `"0"`.